# PyQt5 Missing QtQuick.Studio Module

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-quick

#### Issue

I used Qt Design Studio to create some UI components and screens (.ui.qml format), but no matter what I do, whenever I try to run it in PyQt5 I kept encountering the following error:

```
module "QtQuick.Studio.Components" is not installed
```

The .ui.qml file has an import

```
import QtQuick.Studio.Components 1.0
```

I looked everywhere online and couldn't find much on the topic on how to fix this problem.

#### Question

What's the best way to overcome this issue? I've been using it on Windows but I am mainly looking to use the code on a raspberry pi, are there extra dependencies that need to be installed?

#### Python code

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, Qt, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

if __name__ == '__main__':

    CURRENT_DIRECTORY = Path(__file__).resolve().parent

    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.addImportPath(os.fspath(CURRENT_DIRECTORY.parents[0]))
    url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(os.fspath(CURRENT_DIRECTORY / "Screen01.ui.qml"))

    def handle_object_created(obj, obj_url):
        if obj is None and url == obj_url:
            print("exit")
            QCoreApplication.exit(-1)

    engine.objectCreated.connect(
        handle_object_created, Qt.ConnectionType.QueuedConnection
    )

    engine.load(url)

    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Windows

I used `print(engine.importPathList())` to see my import paths. This prompted me to go `C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/lib/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/qml` and noticed that QtQuick exists but **does not have a Studio folder**.

Since Qt Design Studio can run my code with no import issues, I knew that it would have a Studio folder. Therefore, I went into `C:\Program Files\Qt\qtdesignstudio-2.2.0-community\qt5_design_studio_reduced_version\qml\QtQuick` and copied the Studio folder from there onto the PyQt5 path above.

This fixed the issue.

#### Linux

I am yet to try it on Linux.